# Mass flux in a multicomponent mixture with a concentration-dependent density

Tags: fluid-dynamics, transport-phenomena

This question concerns how to properly calculate the change in mass in a multicomponent mixture when the mass density is concentration-dependent.

For a 1D rod of length $L$ that has a mass density $\rho$ and contains $N$ species with mass concentrations $\rho_1, \rho_2, ... , \rho_N$ such that:
$$
\rho = \sum_{j=1}^N \rho_j
$$

If the densities are always uniform (no dependence on $x$) and there is mass flux at either end of the rod, the mass flux of $j$, $n_j$, at either end would be:
$$
n_j = \rho_j v \quad \quad  (1)
$$
where $v$ is the mass average velocity. The continuity equation for this special case is:
$$
\frac{\partial \rho(t)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(v(x,t) \rho(t) \right) =0 \quad \quad  (2)
$$
The mass average velocity can be found using Eq. 2 and the boundary condition that, at the centre of the rod, $v=0$ due to symmetry. This yields:
$$
v(x,t) = - \frac{x}{\rho }\frac{d \rho(t)}{d t} \quad \quad  (3)
$$
when the center of the rod is at $x=0$.

Inserting Eq. 3 into Eq. 1 gives the following mass fluxes at the ends of the rod:
$$
\left.n_j\right|_{x=L/2} = - \frac{L}{2}\frac{\rho_j}{\rho }\frac{d \rho}{d t} \quad \mathrm{and} \quad\left.n_j\right|_{x=-L/2} =  \frac{L}{2}\frac{\rho_j}{\rho }\frac{d \rho}{d t}
$$
For a total mass $M_j$ of species $j$ in the rod, its rate of change is just the difference between these two fluxes and is:
$$
\frac{d M_j}{dt} = \left.n_j\right|_{x=-L/2}  - \left.n_j\right|_{x=L/2} = L \frac{\rho_j }{\rho }\frac{d \rho}{d t}  \quad \quad  (4)
$$

However, if one just calculates the rate of change of mass from the total mass of $j$ in the rod by taking:
$$
M_j = \rho_j L
$$
and differentiating with respect to time, we get:
$$
\frac{d M_j}{dt} = L \frac{d \rho_j}{d t}  \quad \quad  (5)
$$

My question is the following: Why are Eq. 4 and Eq. 5 not identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, recognize that because the densities are always uniform, the diffusive mass fluxes are always zero. Therefore, the continuity equation for species $j$ in this special case is:
$$
\frac{\partial \rho_j(t)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(v(x,t) \rho_j(t) \right) =0 
$$
Using this equation and following the same analysis as in the question, the mass average velocity will then be
$$
v(x,t) = - \frac{x}{\rho_j }\frac{d \rho_j(t)}{d t}
$$
and then
$$
\left.n_j\right|_{x=L/2} = - \frac{L}{2}\frac{d \rho_j}{d t} \quad \mathrm{and} \quad\left.n_j\right|_{x=-L/2} =  \frac{L}{2}\frac{d \rho_j}{d t}
$$
so that
$$
\frac{d M_j}{dt} = \left.n_j\right|_{x=-L/2}  - \left.n_j\right|_{x=L/2} = L \frac{d \rho_j}{d t}  
$$
which is the same as Eq. 5 in the question.